# Add page break in excel with the module ImportExcel (Powershell)

Tags: excel, xml, powershell, module, page-break

I'm actually trying to generate a large report with multiple groups in powershell. I want to seperate each groups of data in a single page, but I'm struggling to find the method to add a horizontal page break with the ImportExcel module.

I'm starting to wonder if it is doable. I know that it is possible with the excel interlop com object, but the script with be run with an elevated user right on a server, so we do not want to install excel on to.

So far I've look at the module methods and I did not find anything. It seems like we have access to the document/sheets xml so if someone knows how to do it in xml, it could also do the trick.

Comment: I would go directly to the source. Search "Issues" at https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Comment: What does your interop script do?

Comment: I work in schools and we do generate the students list of teacher. I try to seperate each students groups

Comment: @lit I've posted to the issue section. If there is anything new, i'll make sure to come here to updates my question

Comment: do you have an example of how it looks right now compare to how you want it to look like? This will give us a better idea on how you like the outcome to be like.

Comment: Perhaps use COM. Have a look [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1389418-powershell-add-pagebreak-to-excel-worksheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post my answer since I found it. The module ImportExcel is based on the EPPLUS library for c#.

I've take a look in the library and there is a way to add a break line fairy easly, but does not show in powershell.

```
$Sheet.Row($line).PageBreak = $true
```

It's that simple. There is just not obvious documentation and the intellisense was not finding it too.

Comment: Good stuff, I'm going to add this as an example in the repo. https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel